# Не получается создать superuser в Джанго \ проблемы с клавиатурой?

Tags: python, django, cmd

Возникла **очень странная**  проблема с созданием superuser в Джанго. Я ввожу в терминал :

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

Ввожу имя суперпользователя , и-мейл, но при попытке ввести пароль у меня просто не печатаюся символы. Клавиатура работает идеально, но когда я пытаюсь ввести в cmd пароль для суперпользователя , у меня ничего не получается. Что мне делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, ввод пароля для supreuser так и работает: символы печатаемого пароля вообще не показываются, ни при первом вводе, ни при подтверждении.

Это как защита звездочками вместо символов, только еще скрытнее.